# xConnect Installation - Updating Solr Schema for xdb is failing

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

We have upgraded our Sitecore solution from 8.2.4 to 9.0.2 using the guidelines from the Upgrade Guide. Now we are in progress with preparing the xDB data migration.

Using the following script to install the xConnect with SIF

```
Import-Module SitecoreFundamentals
Import-Module SitecoreInstallationFramework

#$global:ProgressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'

#define parameters 
$prefix = "sc90" 
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\xconnect-install"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix" 
$InstallDirectory = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\"
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "C:\solr\solr-6.6.2\" 
$SolrService = "solr-6.6.2" 
$SqlServer = "UXD8SITECOREDB" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword="MyPassword!23" 

#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
    } 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 

#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    InstallDirectory = $InstallDirectory
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = "$prefix"
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
    } 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
```

we ran into

> Problem accessing /solr/sc90_xdb/schema. Reason Not Found

with the error stack trace

> PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask): "The running command
>   stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or
>   common parameter is set to Stop: NotFound -
>   https://localhost:8983/solr/sc90_xdb/schema?wt=json"
>
> > > TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or
> > >       common parameter is set to Stop: NotFound -
> > >       https://localhost:8983/solr/sc90_xdb/schema?wt=json"
> > >       Install-SitecoreConfiguration : NotFound -
> > >       https://localhost:8983/solr/sc90_xdb/schema?wt=json At
> > >       C:\xconnect-install\xconnect-install.ps1:43
> > >       char:1
> > >       + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
> > >       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> > >           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
> > >           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
> > >       Install-SitecoreConfiguration : NotFound -
> > >       https://localhost:8983/solr/sc90_xdb/schema?wt=json At
> > >       C:\xconnect-install\xconnect-install.ps1:43
> > >       char:1
> > >       + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
> > >       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> > >           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
> > >           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

Could anyone give me a hint how to get past this issue?

Comment: I ran into similar issues during an upgrade from 8.2 to 9.1.  Have you verified that $SolrUrl, $SolrRoot, and $SolrService are correct?  For example, my solr installation is from Bitnami so the $SolrRoot value will be different.

Comment: They are correct, the $SolrUrl is secure and I have also updated the SolrRoot DefaultValue in the xconnect-solr.json file to match the $SolrRoot variable

Comment: Do your `xdb` and `xdb_rebuild` cores have a schema set (either directly or a reference to a shared schema)? Both of these cores use the OOTB managed schema that comes with Solr.

Comment: No, I did not create any of the cores mentioned. I was under the impression the script will create all that is needed with xConnect

Comment: Yes, the script should create the cores.  Have you verified if those cores exist?

Comment: They do not exist

Comment: I have both Solr 6.6.2 and Solr. 6.1.0 installed as Windows services and running

Comment: I have managed to get the cores created by running Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path "C:\xconnect-install\xconnect-solr.json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using the script from Sitecore. It has a flaw that is uses two parameter sets that both use the `$solrParams`. So as the script loads it sets `$solrParams` as the `xconnect-solr.json` install. But then it immediately resets it again as the `sitecore-solr.json` install. So when you install xConnect SOLR you are actually running the parameter set of the Sitecore solr install. Your failure is that it expects to find the xDB SOLR that should have been there during the xConnect install.

Notice below the double solrParams.

#### Bad script with double solrParams

```
$solrParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"
 SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
 SolrRoot = $SolrRoot
 SolrService = $SolrService
 CorePrefix = $prefix
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams


$xconnectParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"
 Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002
(OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"
 LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
 Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService
 XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName
 SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
SqlServer = $SqlServer
SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
 SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
 SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
 SolrURL = $SolrUrl

}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams


$solrParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"
 SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
 SolrRoot = $SolrRoot
 SolrService = $SolrService
 CorePrefix = $prefix
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
```

#### Good script with xConnect SOLR renamed

Below you can see I renamed `solrParams` to `xConnectSolrParams`. This will fix your issue.

```
$xConnectSolrParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"
 SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
 SolrRoot = $SolrRoot
 SolrService = $SolrService
 CorePrefix = $prefix
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xConnectSolrParams


$xconnectParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"
 Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002
(OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"
 LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
 Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService
 XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName
 SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
SqlServer = $SqlServer
SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
 SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
 SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
 SolrURL = $SolrUrl

}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams


$solrParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"
 SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
 SolrRoot = $SolrRoot
 SolrService = $SolrService
 CorePrefix = $prefix
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
```

#### Final note

Take a look at Thomas Eldblom's scripts for installing Sitecore. Really cleans up the script a bunch.

https://github.com/Eldblom/sifdemos

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to double check the values you have on the above config and the one on the `xconnect-solr.json`.

Sometimes (and it happened to me) the URL looks like the same but they are not. Instead of `localhost` I had `solr` as the hostname. Those config files can be a little bit confusing.